# CFHTTP - Read data from URL transferring in chunks

Tags: java, coldfusion, chunked-encoding, coldfusion-11, cfhttp

I am trying to get a file from a URL using `cfhttp` but it seems that the provider is sending the data in chunks.

```
<cfhttp
    method="get"
    url="https://www.test.com/somefile.xml">
</cfhttp>
```

The response header is having `Transfer-Encoding` as *chunked* and is missing `Content-Length`.
Also, the `statusCode` is *200 Ok* but the `FileContent` is showing "*Connection Failure*".

Any suggestions?

Comment: What happens if you browse the url?

Comment: @DanBracuk I am able to read the content of the file.

Comment: I vaguely remember running across this same problem a few years ago. Try adding the following request headers: `<cfhttpparam type="Header" name="Accept-Encoding" value="deflate;q=0">
<cfhttpparam type="Header" name="TE" value="deflate;q=0">
`

Comment: @SamM Tried.  Same results. :(

Comment: @Beginner, I wish I could be more help than that. I remember problems with chunked responses. But the website's developer was kind enough to change the responses to include a Content-Length header with the correct value (not 0), which solved the problem. Might be worth a shot to contact the site's admin. As long as Content-Length is the correct value, having it chunked or not ought to be irrelevant.

Comment: @SamM This problem is solved using `java.net.URL` and a continuation to this question is [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35451665/coldfusion-http-chunk-missing-first-character). Thanks for your response :)

Comment: @Beginner I looked at your other question and am impressed with what you came up with to solve this problem. You ought to post that code as an answer to this question.

Answer (score 2):

Finally, I used [`java.net.URL`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/URL.html) to get this working:

```
<cfset local.objURL = createObject(
                          "java"
                        , "java.net.URL"
                      ).init( javaCast( "string" , "https://test.com/abc.xml" ) )>

<!--- Input Stream --->
<cfset local.inputStream = local.objURL.openStream()>

<!--- Get Content --->
<cfset local.objScanner = createObject(
                              "java"
                            , "java.util.Scanner"
                          ).init( local.inputStream ).useDelimiter( "\\A" )>
<cfset local.fileContent = local.objScanner.hasNext() ? local.objScanner.next() : "">
```

Comment: What about using [`IOUtils.toString(myInputStream, "UTF-8");` ?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/350723/104223). It is a bit simpler, and seems to be bundled with CF11.

Comment: @Leigh Oh yes. Thanks for the info. :)

Comment: "Apache" to the rescue :-)  Though the scanner trick is pretty neat too, if you do not have access to the Apache lib.

Answer (score 0):

It is/was probably caused by missing certificate on your CF server for the https connection (keystore file: cf11/jre/lib/security/cacerts).